# Cast or convert DD-MON-YYYY AM/PM to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, casting, type-conversion

I'm stuck in finding an answer on how to convert:
`07-DEC-18 01.00.54.984000 PM` to `2018-12-07 13.00.54.984000`

I think the time of `01.00.54 PM` is 13hours , 0 minutes and 54 seconds

I have try to convert with 112 but still i can't find out how to cast or convert this.

Comment: What data type is this stored in? That's a fundamental piece of the puzzle. Why are you formatting it like that?\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is one method that converts the date and time portions separately, and then uses `DATEADD` to combine the results. This assumes the actual time precision is not greater than milliseconds. Note that you need to use `datetime2` instead of `datetime` to avoid rounding to 1/300 milliseconds.

```
DECLARE @DateTimeString varchar(30) = '07-DEC-18 01.00.54.984000 PM';
SELECT DATEADD(
      millisecond
    , DATEDIFF(millisecond, '', CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@DateTimeString, 11, 8), '.', ':') + RIGHT(@DateTimeString, 10) AS time))
    , CAST(LEFT(@DateTimeString, 9) AS datetime2)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

This converts your value to the datatype it should be, a `datetime2(6)`. Date and time datatypes don't have formats, if you're storing them in a particular format you're doing it wrong (as it means you're storing the value as a `varchar`).

```
DECLARE @YourDate varchar(30) = '07-DEC-18 01.00.54.984000 PM';

SELECT V.YD,
       TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(6),F.FormatedYD,106)
FROM (VALUES(@YourDate)) V(YD)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(STUFF(STUFF(V.YD,13,1,':'),16,1,':'))) F(FormatedYD);
```

If this was a table, then I would fix your actual column datatype by doing the following:

```
UPDATE YT
SET YourDateColumn = CONVERT(varchar(30),TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(6),F.FormatedYD,106),126)
FROM YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(STUFF(STUFF(YT.YourDateColumn,13,1,':'),16,1,':'))) F(FormatedYD);

ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourDateColumn datetime2(6);
```