# Cast-or-convert yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mon-yyyy am/pm

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, casting, type-conversion

I put up a question before on how to convert `07-DEC-18 01.00.54.984000 PM` to `2018-12-07 13.00.54.984000` and got a great answer in this  link: [Cast or convert DD-MON-YYYY AM/PM to YYYY-MM-DD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53682302/cast-or-convert-dd-mon-yyyy-am-pm-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

```
DECLARE @DateTimeString varchar(30) = '07-DEC-18 01.00.54.984000 PM';
SELECT DATEADD(
      millisecond
    , DATEDIFF(millisecond, '', CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@DateTimeString, 11, 8), '.', ':') + RIGHT(@DateTimeString, 10) AS time))
    , CAST(LEFT(@DateTimeString, 9) AS datetime2)
    );
```

This question is now "closed/Approved" so I will put up a new question.

I would like to make this `2018-12-07 13.00.54.984000` into `07-DEC-18 01.00.54.984000 PM`. Its the other way around from my first question.

Comment: Which sql server version fo you have?

Comment: SQL server 2017

Comment: What data type is it?  If its one of the DateTime data types then you just need to format it.  You can use the [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function, note this will result in the value being returned being a string (nvarchar) not a datetime.

Comment: @Nils  Nice question please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - the best advice I can give you is to stop using string representations of DateTime values.
There's only one place where it's good to use a string representation of a dateTime and that's at the presentation level - the UI that use the data.

Having said that, sometimes it's impossible to change the implementation of a system and you're just stuck with what you have - so here's a code example of how to convert a string containing `2018-12-07 13.00.54.984000` to a string containing `07-DEC-18 01.00.54.984000 PM`.

So the first step would obviously be to convert the source string to `DateTime2` - but for that you need to replace the dots between the hours minutes and seconds with colons. 
You can use `STUFF` to do that.

```
DECLARE @DateString varchar(30) = '2018-12-07 13.00.54.984000'

SELECT  CAST(STUFF(STUFF(@DateString, 17, 1, ':'), 14, 1, ':') AS DateTime2);
```

Now, to get the desired string format from `DateTime2` it's simplest to use the `Format` function (though it's worth mentioning it's performance is pretty slow compared to other conversion options - see Aaron Bertrand's [FORMAT() is nice and all, but…](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but))

```
SELECT FORMAT(@DateTime, 'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.fffffff tt')
```

The entire script:

```
DECLARE @DateString varchar(30), @Date DateTime2;

SET @DateString = '2018-12-07 13.00.54.984000'

SELECT  @Date = CAST(STUFF(STUFF(@DateString, 17, 1, ':'), 14, 1, ':') AS DateTime2)

SELECT FORMAT(@Date, 'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.fffffff tt') As Result
```

Result

```
07-Dec-18 01.00.54.9840000 PM
```

Comment: Hi, The source system itself has a varchar datatype for it's dates that is why i'm stuck on finding a way of doing this. This works so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

By using different datetime fucntions and date styles following query has been written

```
DECLARE @TIME DATETIME='2018-12-13 09:58:00.513'

SELECT concat(day(@TIME) ,'-',LEFT(datename(month,@TIME),3), '-',
year(@TIME),' ' ,cast(@TIME as time) ,' ',RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(15),cast(@TIME as time),100),2))
```

output

```
13-Dec-2018 09:58:00.5133333 AM
```

Comment: Yes, This would probably have better performance then `format` for generating the target string from a `DateTime` (or `DateTime2`) value - but this is only one part of the problem - The source string still has to be converted to `DateTime2` (or `DateTime`).

Comment: Hi thank you, however the time is does not give me 01, 02 ,03 and so on... it still gives me 13,14,15 when it PM

Comment: @Nils please make input date format to what ever i passed so it will work as expected

Comment: if oyu change the time to 2018-12-13 13:58:00.513 you will se that the time will still not change to 01 PM but still have 13 PM

Answer (score 1):

```
--to convert to ISO, first preserve the final '.' char by
--converting to a placeholder 'q', with the intention
--of switcing back to '.' at a later stage
--then remove the '-' characters to give ISO date format
--YYYYMMDD
--then change the remaining '.' chars to ':'
--then we switch q back to '.'
--then cast to a datetime2 format
-- from the datetime2 format, the FORMAT
--command is applied with a mask of 
--'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.FFFFFF tt'
--a final stage of convering to upper case
-- is then applied

SELECT  UPPER(
        FORMAT(
        CAST(
            REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE
                            (
                            STUFF(@dat, LEN(@DAT) + 1 - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@DAT)),1,'q'),
                                '.', 
                                ':'             
                            )
                        ,'-', 
                        ''
                        )
                        ,'q',
                        '.'
                    )
            as datetime2
            ),
            'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.FFFFFF tt'
            )
            );
```